# Monitoring /sys/block/*/device/ioerr_cnt, what are typical error rates?

Tags: linux

I am attempting to monitor  /sys/block/*/device/ioerr_cnt for disks that are about to fail. I am seeing healthy disks reporting some errors, as well.

What are typical thresholds to distinguish between disk drives operating normally, and those about to fail? Are there best practices in this area?

Answer (score 1):

[Here's a good discussion on ioerr_cnt](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/435719/why-is-ioerr-cnt-rising-without-showing-any-messages-in-the-log)

It's not a good indicator of drive failure since it's really an indicator of how the drive is responding to commands, not how the actual drive hardware is doing. SMART capable drives, for example, remap bad blocks internally and this may not show up in ioerr_cnt.

Your best bet would be to query the drive (if it is SMART capable), since it keeps track of actual error rates and remapped blocks.

Comment: I agree that the best info is going to come from SMART queries, but we are encountering a failure mode where a query against a failing drive will hang indefinitely, and therefore fail to alert... This is why we are looking at alternate approaches. In our case, it seems like failing drives generate ioerr_cnt events hundreds of times faster that healthy drives, but I am not sure how reliable that is...

Comment: You might want to look at Nagios and set it to check the SMART data every x minutes. You can set it to alert you on "no response" as well as on drive or controller failure.

Comment: Note: Nagios will monitor pretty much anything, so you can have it monitor the controller, the drives, system components, network traffic, temperature, etc. It can also alert humans as necessary and even respects on-call status so if it's 3am and you're not on call, your phone doesn't go off. 8-)

Comment: We already do something similar, the checks call smartctl, which in turns enters uninterruptable state, and hangs, causing thousands of orphaned processes. This is what I am trying to avoid, I figure simply reading from /sys should never hang in this manner...

Wouldn't there be some correlation between how the drive is responding to commands, versus the health of the hardware?

Comment: @MikeKlopot smartctl shouldn't hang. There was a very old bug that caused this, but was supposedly fixed. The SMART drives are very good at diagnosing their own impending failure. If you're getting hangs in smartctl , I suspect it's not the drive.

Comment: Interesting point. I am confused about versioning here, the smartmon site says: "Smartmontools 6.6 was released 2017-11-05, see NEWS​, ChangeLog​ and tickets for details"


and I am showing from `smartctl --version`:


"smartmontools release 6.6 dated 2016-05-07 at 11:17:46 UTC
smartmontools SVN rev 4324 dated 2016-05-31 at 20:45:50"


Am I actually running the latest version?


Could it be related to the firmware releases on the drives themselves? Or have anything to do with SAS expanders?


smartctl is _definitely_ hanging for us...

Comment: Sorry, I don't know. You might see if they have a mailing list.